# Look before you migrate

Tags: discussion, migration

https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/271583/what-step-up-booster-transformer-would-be-needed-to-wire-a-227v-ptac-unit-into-1 was just migrated to DIY. The OP had already posted their own copy of the same question directly on DIY and received an answer long before the migration.

The migration should not have been performed. We on DIY don’t need to be forced to waste time closing a dupe when it could have just been left here, closed.

Please always carefully check they questions are actually on-topic and not already duplicated before migrating to DIY.

Comment: Now I know why electronics.se guys are so tense about migrating to DIY.

Comment: Did the moderators not have a chance to reject it in thier que?

Comment: It must be very quiet and orderly over there :-)

Comment: Hey! +1 -5 - where's the solidarity ? :-)

Answer (score 11):

Rules about cross-posting are rather clear ([Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068)): cross-posting is highly discouraged, and, if done, posts should explictly indicate that they have been cross-posted. Therefore, the original poster made two mistakes:

1. Posting something off-topic at electronics.se
2. Breaking the cross-posting rules.

Moderators here tried to correct the first mistake, but you can't expect them to triple-check every other mistakes users can possibly make. What happened was unfortunate, but you should blame the original poster here, not the moderators.